# What is the proper way to modify an Exported Symbols File in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, symbols, exp

I am modifying an existing projects framework, its is a custom JavaScriptCore framework.  The JavaScriptCore Export Symbol File is included in the project.  How do I properly add a function to the list.

They look cryptic like this:

```
__ZN3WTF21RefCountedLeakCounterD1Ev
__ZN3WTF23callOnMainThreadAndWaitEPFvPvES0_
__ZN3WTF23dayInMonthFromDayInYearEib
__ZN3WTF23waitForThreadCompletionEjPPv
__ZN3WTF27releaseFastMallocFreeMemoryEv
__ZN3WTF28setMainThreadCallbacksPausedEb
```

So how do I add function name with the correct prefix and suffix on it?

Is there a tool that I am missing or a step I am missing, nothing seems to change this file, except for me doing it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Unix command line too nm:

http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?nm

nm will print the symbol table of an binary.  Then you can find your method in the list and cut and paste that into your export symbol file.